# SOAP response handling

Tags: xpath, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a SOAP service which I am trying to access via a API in WSO2 ESB.

below is the response body from a method of that SOAP service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="wom">
       <SOAP-ENV:Body>
          <ns1:OrderResponse>
             <return>
                <ResponseHeader>
                   <ResponseCode>1</ResponseCode>
                   <Description>CIR is already exists</Description>
                </ResponseHeader>
             </return>
          </ns1:OrderResponse>
       </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And I followed the following link to access Body/OrderResponse of above xml response.

[https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Synapse+XPath+Variables#SynapseXPathVariables-$body][1]

below is the outSequence tag in api which I tried to log the property value.

```
<outSequence>
    <log level="custom">
       <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                 name="ErrorCode"
                 expression="$body/ns1:OrderResponse"
                 scope="default"
                 type="STRING"/>
    </log>
</outSequence>
```

I tried both **$body/ns1:OrderResponse** and **$body/OrderResponse** but ErrorCode property is null in the log.
but when I try **$body** whole response can be taken (which is same as the xml response I mentioned before). How can I get only the OrderResponse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ns1 is not defined in your property, try with :

```
<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
xmlns:ns1="wom"
name="ErrorCode"
expression="$body/ns1:OrderResponse"
scope="default"
type="STRING"/>
```

If you want the xml payload, define you property with type="OM"